# Are datasets different?

Tags: experimental-physics

In the experiment we measure some parameter $y$ as function of other parameter $x$ at different times (conditions) obtaining ${x_i,y_i}$. However the datasets seems to depend on time when we have taken them, but I have no tool for prove or disapprove my hypothesis. Are there any?

For simplicity lets consider two datasets ${x^1_i,y^1_i}$ and ${x^2_i,y^2_i}$ with equal errors ($\Delta x_i,\Delta y_i = \Delta$). How can I say if both datasets describes the same physical situation?

Comment: You could use a statistical test (e.g., Pearson's chi-squared test). Perhaps you may want to migrate this question to [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Your question contains no physics in it. Questions like "Are these two set of figures drawn from the same underlying probability distribution?" are very much the domain of statistics whatever the meaning of the numbers themselves.